# How to quit all the Firefox processes which gets initiated through GeckoDriver and Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using python 3.7 + selenium + geckodriver.exe + firefox 70.0.1x64,I know `driver.quit()` could close firefox window,but in some situation I can not quit firefox totally,I do not know why,this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def func1():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if i > 10 and driver is not None:
                driver.quit()
                driver = None
                print('quit success')
            i += 1
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            if driver is not None:
                driver.quit()
                driver = None
                print('keyboard quit success')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func1()
```

With this code,there are tow ways to close firefox window:

1-wait 10 seconds.

2-use Ctrl+C.

**Then I test method 1**

```
python test1.py
```

When firefox winodw showed,I notice there are 6 process in task manager,like this
[image]

Then I wait 10 seconds,everything is fine,6 process is gone,like this:

[image]

**Then I test method 2**

I press Ctrl+C in 10 seconds,result like this:

[image]

You can see that there are still 5 process alive,only 1 process is gone,I do not know why,Can anyone help me?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When *automated tests* are getting executed through *Mozilla Firefox* as you have observed that there are potentially half a dozen of *Mozilla Firefox* processes are running which can be observed through Windows Task Manager's `Processes` tab.

[image: Multi-Process Firefox]

---

### Multi-Process Firefox

As per the article [Multi-Process Firefox: everything you need to know](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/07/22/multi-process-firefox/) to improve the browser's stability, performance and security *Firefox* had increased the number of content processes to four for the stable population in Firefox and is now multi-process Firefox which is also known as **Electrolysis** or **e10S**. Multi-process architecture helps in separating tasks into processes as **Electrolysis** functionality hosts, renders, or executes web related content in background child processes which communicate with the "parent" Firefox browser via various ipdl protocols. Additionally, multi-process Firefox moves NPAPI plugins, media playback and web content to child processes thus separating them from the browser's core.

---

### Details

You can observe that several `firefox.exe` processes when you run a process manager, i.e. the Windows Task Manager which essentially implies that **Electrolysis** is enabled. Apparently Firefox should run just like before but ideally enabling multi-process functionality should improve the browser's performance and stability right away. However, you may however notice a higher than usual RAM usage. Mozilla confirmed that Firefox with Electrolysis will use about **20%** more **RAM**. You may change how many processes Firefox uses for its multi-process functionality.

---

### This usecase

In your first usecase when you invoke `driver.quit()` the parent and all the child Firefox processes and the parent Firefox process gets destroyed programatically.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

In your second usecase, you have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> after **4** was printed, when **`KeyboardInterrupt`** occurs and your program is **aborted** and presumably *GeckoDriver* looses the control of the *Mozilla Firefox* browser process. However, still **1** process gets terminated through `driver.quit()` but the rest processes remains dangling.

---

### Outro

You can find a relevant discussion in [Many process of Google Chrome (32 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400613/many-process-of-google-chrome-32-bit/57411466#57411466)

Comment: Thank you very much,I think you are right,after I test,I found that after I press Ctrl + C,6 process change to 5 process even without driver.quit(),it must because Ctrl + C lead to shutdown firefox before geckodriver,I decide to use 'keyboard' module instead Ctrl + C.problem solved.thanks.