# Python script with Selenium leaves firefox.exe running when manually closing application

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I have a simple script that runs on Selenium.
I made an .exe file out of it and it works perfectly fine but there is one problem I have noticed.
The .exe opens a console as intended but if I manually close the console while the script is running, it leaves firefox.exe opened in Processes tab.

[image: zombie processes after manually closing .exe]

My question is: how do I make Python close these processes in case if the script's execution has been interrupted manually?

I'm guessing I need to catch the exception, but what exception does Python throw in case if we manually stop the program?

Comment: Did you use `pyinstaller` to pack it?

Comment: Yes. I did use `pyinstaller`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, invoking `quit()` deletes the current instance of [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) variant and the current *Browsing Context*.

However, if you are manually interupting the script's execution by closing the console, the *Browsing Context* gets closed visually but numerous [browser processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830622/how-to-quit-all-the-firefox-processes-which-gets-initiated-through-geckodriver-a/58833151#58833151) would still continue to consume [CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701824/limit-chrome-headless-cpu-and-memory-usage/52680811#52680811) and [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)

---

### Solution

In those cases, you have to explicitly kill the *Browser* process and the *WebDriver* instances using either of the following solutions:

- Java Solution(Windows):

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;

  public class Kill_ChromeDriver_GeckoDriver_IEDriverserver 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM geckodriver.exe /T");
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T");
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe /T");
      }
  }
  ```
- Python Solution (Windows):

  ```
  import os
  os.system("taskkill /f /im geckodriver.exe /T")
  os.system("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe /T")
  os.system("taskkill /f /im IEDriverServer.exe /T")
  ```
- Python Solution(**Cross Platform**):

  ```
  import os
  import psutil

  PROCNAME = "geckodriver" # or chromedriver or IEDriverServer
  for proc in psutil.process_iter():
      # check whether the process name matches
      if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
          proc.kill()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`atexit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) to quit the webdriver automatically before the script stopped.

```
import atexit
from selenium import webdriver

def exit_handler(): # when exit, execute this function
    driver.quit()

atexit.register(exit_handler)

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
# Your work
```

Comment: I used `psutil` in my def `exit_handler` and it did not work, unfortunately...

Comment: @audreysylvainfanaccount You don't need to use `psutil`...Have you tried `atexit`?

Comment: Yeah, the `psutil` part was called via `def exit_handler` which was registered with `atexit`

However, I did not try `driver.quit()` since I have no idea how to properly pass it from a thread yet, because drivers are being generated by `ThreadPoolExecutor().map()`