# console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)")) using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm doing a basic Selenium test program in Java and I notice I'm getting this warning, which is annoying.

```
 console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
```

My code before the driver.get is:

```
 FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
 options.setProfile(new FirefoxProfile());
 options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.FATAL);
 options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
 options.setHeadless(true);
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

What do I need to do to get rid of this warning? The older versions of Selenium never did this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
```

...implies that the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context*.

The most probable reason is there is/are dangling/zombie [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) instances clinging on with the `scoped_dir*`s. As a result no new `scoped_dir` can be created.

---

### Solution

You need to invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully at the end of each execution. Incase the dangling/zombie [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453) process still continues to occupy your system memory you need to forcefully kill them.

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Error: Can't find profile directory. console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" using GeckoDriver Firefox and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65561285/7429447)
- [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)
- [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)
- [How to quit all the Firefox processes which gets initiated through GeckoDriver and Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830622/how-to-quit-all-the-firefox-processes-which-gets-initiated-through-geckodriver-a/58833151#58833151)