# Python Selenium - Does it close after crash?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have quick question about selenium browser automation after it crashes on for example linux server does it close automatically after certain period of time? Cleaning memory?

Answer (score 1):

In case of a crash, there are two distinct objects involved, the *WebDriver* and the *Web Browser*. Considering the *ChromeDriver* and *Google Chrome* browser combination either of the following crash can happen:

- The ChromeDriver crash.
- The Chrome Browser crash.

---

### ChromeDriver crash

In case of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) crash in [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) systems you may see an error message like this:

[image: chromedriver_exe]

After the crash, the zombie chromedriver process may still continue to occupy your system memory and resources. In those cases you have to kill the dangling instances of ChromeDriver with brute force.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

---

### Chrome Browser crash

In case of [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) crashing just closing the crashed window may not be sufficient. You may require to kill the other associated processes as well with brute force.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Many process of Google Chrome (32 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400613/many-process-of-google-chrome-32-bit/57411466#57411466)

The behaviour with other [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) and Web Browser variants will be more or less similar.