# In new google chrome version (Version 87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) (64-bit) did they rename "chromedriver.exe" process to "google chrome"?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

In the earlier versions of the chromedriver, I used to see a process with the `chromedriver.exe` name in task manager. But now it seems in the newer version (87) they have renamed the `chromedriver.exe` process to `Google Chrome`.

So the point is i used to kill all the unused chromedriver.exe process with the below code -
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM ChromeDriver.exe");`

Need to know it will still work? or we have to change the code to (Something like that) ? -
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM Google Chrome");`

[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Vs Driver.quit()?

Comment: @DMart - What i am trying to accomplish? - Closing all the chromedriver.exe process which are abandoned or say not used because my code broke down in between before reaching the driver.quit() code. And as per my knowledge i think the driver.quit() will close the current chromedriver and not the one which was running earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest *ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 (2020-10-15)* with *Google Chrome* **Version 87.0.4280.66** executing a simple test it is observed that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) executable process is still identified as **chromedriver.exe**

Snapshot:

[image: chromedriver_executable_process]

---

### Conclusion

Hence there is no change to the process name of *chromedriver.exe*.

Perhaps the numerous processes of *Google Chrome* which can be seen are the result of [Many process of Google Chrome (32 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400613/many-process-of-google-chrome-32-bit/57411466#57411466)

Answer (score 0):

Looks into ProcessHandle, rather than using the command line:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html
Get all handles, then filter on command name, then destroy the process:

```
ProcessHandle.allProcesses()
        .filter(ph -> ph.info().command().isPresent() && ph.info().command().get().contains("SomeJavaApp"))
        .forEach((process) -> {
            process.destroy();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there wasn't any change in this direction. In 'Processes' you're actually seeing all `chrome.exe` processes. If you don't expect them, they're probably defunct processes. You can have a better overview in the 'Details' tab, with the actual process names. You can see also the `chromedriver.exe` running processes, if there are some.